# Is is possible to link to yourself in a Google Plus post?

Tags: google-plus

I've often linked to other people in Google Plus posts, but I recently had a need to make a post with sort of a list of users in a Google Community. I noticed, that there is apparently no way to link to myself +start_typing_my_name just doesn't seem to work like it does for +anyone_in_my_circles.

Am I missing something? Is there a secret +me or +myself or something? Or am I just out of luck?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use Google+.

Comment: Belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry if i posted this to the wrong area, saw some similar posts about formatting here, figured it was related. Mea culpa. Mods please feel free to move this where it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can +plus mention yourself. The easiest way to do this is to make sure you are in one of your own circles, but it will generally pickup on your name.

Another trick is to mention yourself using the + followed by the incredibly long profile ID that shows up if you're looking at your profile. This will get translated to your name and the correct link by Google+.

Finally, instead of +plus mentioning a bunch of people, it is common to make a shared circle (and include yourself in that circle). This makes it easy for others to add the people in question, if that is what you're trying to do.

Comment: Awesome. +<google id> did the trick for me. In this specific case it is a list of individual Ingress usernames next to their respective Google+ names.. so a circle just won't do. This worked perfectly. It doesn't highlight the name as you type it, but once saved it worked as expected.